# Is any way to use Google Invisible reCaptcha in Magento 1.9 admin login?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

How can I use Google Invisible reCaptcha in Magento 1.9 admin login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one free extension out [here](https://magecomp.com/magento-google-recaptcha.html) which has the feature of enabling **Google Recaptcha** on Magento Admin login page, but it is **not** for enabling **Google Invisible Recaptcha**. See if that helps you.